# How to store JWT's in cookies with FastApi?

Tags: jwt, fastapi, cookie-httponly

I am creating a basic Login system with FastApi, React and MongoDb.
I want to store the JWT's in cookies, but nothing worked for me and i really don't want to store them in LocalStorage...
Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
@app.post("/login")
 async def login(response:Response,data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm=Depends()):
 username = data.username
 password = data.password

 user = await query_user(username)
 if not user:
    raise InvalidCredentialsException
 if not verify_password(password,user["password"]):
    raise InvalidCredentialsException

 access_token = accessToken.create(user)
 refresh_token = refreshToken.create(user)

 response.set_cookie(key="access_token",value=f"Bearer {access_token}", httponly=True)
 response.set_cookie(key="refresh_token",value=f"Bearer {access_token}", httponly=True)
 return response
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to prefix anything with `Bearer` if you're setting cookies, and you're using `access_token` as the value for both refresh and access token. However, if you're using React, you'll have to make sure that the cookies are set and returned as you plan - since 3rd party cookies are getting banned in more and more browsers, you'll have to serve both your react app and your backend from the same host. What does "nothing really works for me" mean? Do you get the cookies set in the response? Are they included in any future requests? How are you making requests?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy. In my case, once the user logs in successfully, I redirect to dashboard and then set the token in the cookies.

```
@app.post('/token', tags=["authenticate"])
async def login_for_access_token(response:Response, request_form: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    token = await token_generator(request_form.username, request_form.password,
                                  expires_delta=access_token_expires)

    response = RedirectResponse(url='/api/v1/dashboard', status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
    response.set_cookie(key="access_token", value=f"Bearer {token[0]}", httponly=True)
    return response
```

My token consists of both the access_token and user_id keys, hence the token[0]. As you will notice, the 'httponly' flag is set to True. This is a security feature as there is no way to access anything about the HttpOnly cookies from "non-HTTP" APIs, e.g. JavaScript. By design, neither reading nor writing such cookies is possible. HttpOnly header flag became a standard, defined in section 5.2.6 of RFC6265, with the storage semantics described in the same document (look for "http-only-flag" throughout the RFC text). Hope this helps, good luck!